# Search node recursion error binary search tree - C++

Tags: c++, search, binary-tree

to keep this is as minimal as possible, I have a recursive binary tree function like this:

```
template <class T>

bool Bst<T>::searchTree(const nodeType<T>* p, const T& searchItem) const
{
    if(p == nullptr)
    {
        cout << "Cannot search an empty tree." << endl;
        return false;     //If root is nullptr, that means there is no root node hence no binary tree to begin with
    }
    else
    {
        if(p->info == searchItem)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if(p->info > searchItem)
        {
            return searchTree(p->rLink, searchItem);
        }
        else
        {
            return searchTree(p->lLink, searchItem);
        }
                                                    //Sets the root node to the pointer current
    }
}
```

This function is made use of by another function:

```
template <class T>
bool Bst<T>::searchTreeRecursive(const T& searchItem) const
{
    return searchTree(root, searchItem);
}
```

And I use it in one of my main methods like this:

```
if(dateTree.searchTreeRecursive(newDate))
    {
        cout << "Date has been found." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Date not found." << endl;
    }
```

Where `newDate` is an object of a class called Date, and `dateTree` is a binary search tree that holds dates inside it. The BST is fine after insertion because when doing traversal to output all the values are there.

My problem is, my searchTree function meets the condition that `p==nullptr` (p is root) and returns false, even when I know the date I've entered exists in the BST. Can anyone spot out problems with my code and help me out?

EDIT: For the very first date value in my BST, if i search for that it returns correctly. For every value after the first in the BST, its apparently nullptr.
Thanks

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal reproducible example? What is the type of newDate?

Comment: Replace the `elseif/else` blocks with just `else return searchTree(p->rLink, searchItem) || searchTree(p->lLink, searchItem);`. If that works, recheck how you build the binary tree in the first place. If it still doesn't, recheck the `==` and `>` operators for the `T` type used in testing.

Comment: The most likely problem is that your tree construction code is faulty and the tree really only contains that first node. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: It could also be a problem with `Date`. Test with `int` and `std::string`.